# matching word with special characters

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I am using AndroidStudio for developing an app.
My App reads a text from the internet and AndroidStudio shows me the text (//)

```
String mytext = getText();   // mytext = "unité"
```

I try to find a match with the word "unité", but I don't succeed.

when

```
String wordToCompare = "unité";  // wordToCompare = "unitÃ©"

if (mytext.equals(wordToCompare)){
    System.out.println("matched !");
}else{
    System.out.println("no match !");
}
```

it will go to "no match !", because "unitÃ©" != "unité"

How can I set the String variable wordToCompare , so it will match ?

Comment: You are using the UTF-8 charset correct?

Comment: Do you mean the File in AndroidStudio ? Yes its marked as UTF-8 at the bottom of AndroidStudio. Should I change it ?

Comment: UTF-8 is what you want. Java Strings are stored in UTF-16. Try doing this `String wordToCompare = new String(mytext.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by just switching the file to "ISO-8859-1".

We can see the encoding-characterset in the bottom of AndroidStudio and there we can also switch to ohter charactersets. After switching AndroidStudio asks to reload or convert. After converting the file is stored as "ISO-8859-1".

AndroidStudio will change the specific file and ".idea/encodings.xml".

Now it works.